# Kendo Grid changes are not reflected in Source object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My bound objects have setters and while changing values in the grid cells, the setters are not getting called. Why?

```
function PresonDetails(_contactName, _contactTitle, _country, _companyName) {

Object.defineProperties(this, {
    "ContactName": {
        get: function () {
            return this._contactName;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            alert("New ContactName is :" + value)
            this._contactName = value; //Setter is not get called when i change the value in grid.
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
        "ContactTitle": {
        get: function () {
            return this._contactTitle;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._contactTitle = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
        "Country": {
        get: function () {
            return this._country;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._country = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
        "CompanyName": {
        get: function () {
            return this._companyName;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._companyName = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});

this.ContactName = _contactName;
this.ContactTitle = _contactTitle;
this.Country = _country;
this.CompanyName = _companyName;
}

(function () {
    var details = [];
    details.push(new PresonDetails("ContactName1", "ContactTitle", "USA", "MICro")); 


    var $grid = $('#grid');
    $grid.kendoGrid({
        scrollable: true,
        dataSource: details,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: false,
        editable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 200
        }, {
            field: "ContactTitle",
            title: "Contact Title",
            width: 250
        }, {
            field: "CompanyName",
            title: "Company Name"
        }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: 150,
        }]
    });
})();
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4g8S/128/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is not called *but* that's correct.

Well, what I mean is that when you bind an array (and that is what you have defined as `details`), Kendo UI converts it to an [`ObservableObject`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject) -actually a [`DataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource) that internally uses an [`ObservableArray`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observablearray) that is an array of `ObservableObjects`- but that doesn't mean that uses your object definition. What it does is creating an `ObservableObject` **from** your data but internally uses their own [`Model`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model).

So, what you should do is defining a `Model` for your object and there you can define a [set](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model#methods-set) and a [get](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model#methods-get) method.